# how to convert unix timestamp to datetime in django's templete?

Tags: django

First:
My database is Mysql,and the table has exists,it been used for php,all the time fileds'type is unix_timestamp.

the query result return an unix timestamp string.  how to convert the unix timestamp to datetime in django's templete?

second:

about regex,

my code here:

```
import re
pattern=re.compile("^\d+$")
if pattern.match(50):
  print 1
else:
  print 0
```

but it show me "TypeError" why ?

Thanks!

My english is very pool~!  I'm sorry

Answer (score 8):

Second:

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r"^\d+$")
if pattern.match(u"50"):
    print 1
else:
    print 0
```

First:

I can offer a custom template filter, which converts timestamp to python datetime object:

```
@register.filter(name='fromunix')
def fromunix(value):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(value))
```

Template:

```
{{ obj.unixtime|fromunix|date:"F" }}}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters

Comment: Thanks very much~! I love you !o(∩_∩)o！

Comment: if like this

 cid=request.GET.get("cid",1)

if pattern.match(cid):
    print 1
else:
    print 0

and what should i do ?thanks

Comment: Do not validate url in views, instead write correct regexp in [urls.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls)